# How to add a simple button in a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, option-type

I have the following code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button : UIButton?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton?
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I get the following error

**ERROR:**

```
'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'UIButton?'
```

I know I might be doing something fundamentally wrong. I would like to know what that is.

According to me:
I have declared **button** as an **Optional UIButton**
- Which I think means, that the value of **button** can be unset or nil

Therefore, 
while initialising it the type is mentioned **as UIButton?**

Is this it right way ?

Comment: this one will work  button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as? UIButton

Comment: I see, can you tell me why ?

Comment: becuse buttonWithType returns AnyObject and you should not consider again casting to a optional UIButton as UIButton?

Comment: to be more clear..you are defining your button as optional..and again trying to cast a button to a optional Button will probably not let you do..instead try to cast a optional button using as? which returns nil if it fails to cast

Comment: Ah, thanks :) That makes more sense !

Comment: great it could be a liittle help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast to an optional UIButton in the way you're doing it. The correct way to cast to an optional UIButton is:

```
button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as? UIButton
```

Interpret this as: This cast can either return nil or an UIButton object, resulting in an optional UIButton object.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(150, 240, 75, 30))
button.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: I do not want the button to be local variable. I need it to be an object variable.

Comment: var button = UIButton()  as globle object

Comment: var button = UIButton()  after  import UIKit  for globle object

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below code

```
var myBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
  //OR
var myBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
  //OR
var myBtn = UIButton()
myBtn.setTitle("Add Button To View Controller", forState: .Normal)
myBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
myBtn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 200, 400)
myBtn.addTarget(self, action: "actionPress:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(myBtn)

//Button Action
func actionPress(sender: UIButton!) 
{
   NSLog("When click the button, the button is %@", sender.tag) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the job.

```
button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
```

In this case the `force cast` done with the `!` is a safe option because the documentation does guarantee that the method returns a `UIButton`.

You can also create the button during the declaration of the property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    ...
```

This way there is no need to declare the property as an optional type.